# How to clear directory contents in c++ on Linux (basically, i want to do 'rm -rf <directorypath>/*'

Tags: c++, linux, directory

I am writing a c++ program on Linux (Ubuntu). I would like to delete the contents of a directory. It can be loose files or sub-directories.

Essentially, i would like to do something equivalent to

```
rm -rf <path-to-directory>/*
```

Can  you suggest the best way of doing this in c++ along with the required headers.
Is it possible to do this with sys/stat.h or sys/types.h or sys/dir.h ?!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With Boost it's done with [`remove_all`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_31_0/libs/filesystem/doc/index.htm)

Answer (score 31):

Use the [`nftw()`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man3/nftw.3.html) (File Tree Walk) function, with the `FTW_DEPTH` flag.  Provide a callback that just calls `remove()` on the passed file:

```
#define _XOPEN_SOURCE 500
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ftw.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int unlink_cb(const char *fpath, const struct stat *sb, int typeflag, struct FTW *ftwbuf)
{
    int rv = remove(fpath);

    if (rv)
        perror(fpath);

    return rv;
}

int rmrf(char *path)
{
    return nftw(path, unlink_cb, 64, FTW_DEPTH | FTW_PHYS);
}
```

If you don't want to remove the base directory itself, change the `unlink_cb()` function to check the level:

```
int unlink_cb(const char *fpath, const struct stat *sb, int typeflag, struct FTW *ftwbuf)
{
    int rv;

    if (ftwbuf->level == 0)
        return 0;

    rv = remove(fpath);

    if (rv)
        perror(fpath);

    return rv;
}
```

Comment: You should also add the FTW_PHYS flag to correctly handle symbolic links (meaning don't follow them).

Comment: What plays the role of "-f" in this code? What if you just want a regular "rm -r"?

Comment: @static_rtti: If you just want regular `-r` then you need to specifically check for unwriteable files and prompt the user whether to remove them.

Answer (score -5):

```
system ("rm -rf <path-to-directory>");
```

Comment: big giant whopping safety risk

Comment: That's not a security risk, any more than the question is. OP asked for the equivalent of `rm -rf <path-to-directory>/*` which this pretty much is (other than the fact it will remove the top-level directory as well).

Comment: Just came across this post. Why is this a security risk?

Comment: Ram Bhat, it's not a security risk. sehe calls it a "safety" risk, probably referring to the possibility that you might accidentally type something like "sudo rm -rf /" while you meant to do something else

Comment: It's a security risk, if the user can control the argument, which could be something like `foo; echo 'command injection 101'`

Comment: @domen: if the user controls the arguments with the accepted solution, he can already wipe the whole system, so...

Comment: @static_rtti wanted functionality is "delete everything in a directory", `system` here will potentially give you arbitrary code execution. I do agree that path argument if supplied from outside (and even if not!) should probably first be resolved by `realpath` and then checked if beginning matches allowed beginning and only then nftw+unlink way would be used.

Comment: In other words: I believe it to be a security bug, when my custom "rm" also has ability to execute the arguments.