# Recursive file delete in C on Linux

Tags: c, unix

I have a C program that, at one point in the program has this:

```
system("rm -rf foo");
```

Where foo is a directory.  I decided that, rather than calling system, it would be better to do the recursive delete right in the code.  I assumed a piece of code to do this would be easy to find.  Silly me.  Anyway, I ended up writing this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <dirent.h>
#include <libgen.h>

int recursiveDelete(char* dirname) {

  DIR *dp;
  struct dirent *ep;

  char abs_filename[FILENAME_MAX];

  dp = opendir (dirname);
  if (dp != NULL)
    {
      while (ep = readdir (dp)) {
        struct stat stFileInfo;

        snprintf(abs_filename, FILENAME_MAX, "%s/%s", dirname, ep->d_name);

        if (lstat(abs_filename, &stFileInfo) < 0)
          perror ( abs_filename );

        if(S_ISDIR(stFileInfo.st_mode)) {
          if(strcmp(ep->d_name, ".") && 
             strcmp(ep->d_name, "..")) {
            printf("%s directory\n",abs_filename);
            recursiveDelete(abs_filename);
          }
        } else {
          printf("%s file\n",abs_filename);
                  remove(abs_filename);
        }
          }
      (void) closedir (dp);
        }
  else
    perror ("Couldn't open the directory");


  remove(dirname);
  return 0;

}
```

This seems to work, but I'm too scared to actually use it in production.  I'm sure I've done something wrong. Is there a way in C to do recursive delete I've missed, or can someone point out any mistakes I've made?

Comment: Actually, when you pass something to shell it goes to the Operating System and it runs in machine code. The Unix kernel is extremely optimized, so even if you coded it EXACTLY how it's coded in the Unix kernel you'd probably only see a 5-10% performance increase. It's just too easy and convenient to pass to shell.

Comment: See [
Delete folder with items
](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1149764/delete-folder-with-items) and [Removing a non empty directory programmatically in C or C++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2256945/removing-a-non-empty-directory-programmatically-in-c-or-c-closed).

Comment: Interesting: POSIX specification for `remove()` says `unlink()` on non-directories (files, symlinks, etc) and `rmdir()` on directories.
You should be checking that `remove()` works - and reporting if not.  You should look at what happens if the argument to the function is not a directory - it complains it could not open the directory (but doesn't say which one; that's bad too), and then removes it anyway (or attempts to).

Answer (score 13):

POSIX has a function called [ftw(3)](http://linux.die.net/man/3/ftw) (file tree walk) that

> walks through the directory tree that is located under the directory dirpath, and calls fn() once for each entry in the tree.

Comment: Yup. POSIX to the rescue. It's probably safer, faster, and catches little errors you won't always get during normal operation of a manual traverse.

Comment: There's also the new FTW function - [nftw](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/nftw.html) with a slightly different interface.

Comment: `nftw` is what you're after - see [this answer to the same question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3184445/how-to-clear-directory-contents-in-c-on-linux-basically-i-want-to-do-rm-rf/3184915#3184915).

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest one additional precaution that you can take.

Almost always when you delete multiple files and/or directories it would be a good idea to chroot() into the dir before executing anything that can destroy your data outside this directory.

Answer (score 1):

kudos for being scared to death, that's a healthy attitude to have in a case like this.

I have no library to suggest in which case you have two options:

1) 'run' this code exhaustively 
  a) not on a machine; on paper, with pencil.  take an existing directory tree, list all the elements and run the program through each step, verify that it works 
  b) compile the code but replace all of the deletion calls with a line that does a printf - verify that it does what it should do 
  c) re-insert the deletion calls and run

2) use your original method (call system())

Answer (score 1):

I think you will need to call closedir() before recursiveDelete() (because you don't want/need all the directories open as you step into them.  Also closedir()  before calling remove() because  remove() will probably give an error on the open directory.  You should step through this once carefully to make sure that readdir() does not pickup the '..'.  Also be wary of linked directories, you probably wouldn't want to recurse into directories that are 
symbolic or hard links.