# Recursively remove a directory using C

Tags: c, linux, recursion, filesystems

I want to implement this myself and I come up something like this:

```
/* DIR *opendir(const char *name);
 *
 * Open a directory stream to argv[1] and make sure
 * it's a readable and valid (directory) */
if ((dip = opendir(argv[1])) == NULL)
{
        perror("opendir");
        return 0;
}

printf("Directory stream is now open\n");

/*  struct dirent *readdir(DIR *dir);
 *
 * Read in the files from argv[1] and print */
while ((dit = readdir(dip)) != NULL)
{
        printf("\n%s", dit->d_name);
        remove(dit->d_name);
}
```

I am guessing I have to start delete things from the deepest level and then go up, but now it seems readdir does not give me that order.

Please help, thanks!

Comment: Please see this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3184445/how-to-clear-directory-contents-in-c-on-linux-basically-i-want-to-do-rm-rf/3184915#3184915

Comment: thanks, i have to code this out, not allowed to used other things

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to recurse all the way down to the lower levels first, as in the following pseudo code:

```
def delDir (d):
    # Delete the directories by recursion, files straight away.

    for every item in d:
        if item is a directory:
            delDir (item)
        else:
            delete file item

    # Finally, remove the directory itself.

    remove directory d
```

That's it really, this guarantees that all lower directories and files are deleted before you attempt to remove the parent.

---

Since `item` is likely to be just the current component of the directory, you may need to construct a full name using, for example, `strcpy/strcat`:

```
def delDir (dirName):
    def localBuff[enoughSpace]

    # Delete the directories by recursion, files straight away.

    dirHandle = dirOpen (dirName)
    itemName = dirnext (dirHandle)
    while itemName is valid:
        if itemName <> "." and itemName <> "..":
            strcpy dirName to localBuff
            strcat "/" to localBuff
            strcat itemName to localBuff

            if itemName is a directory:
                delDir (localBuff)
           else:
                delete file localBuff

        itemName = dirnext (dirHandle)

    dirClose (dirHandle)

    # Finally, remove the directory itself.

    remove directory dirName
```

Comment: Instead of two loops, why not have an `else: delete file item` in the first?

Comment: @Joachim, that's a good point. Modified to make more efficient. I think that's actually a hangover from my early MSDOS days where you could ask for directories specifically with findfirst/findnext. That, and the old Wordstar 3.3 CTRL-K/CTRL-X exit sequence have _long_ outlived their usefulness :-)

Comment: thank you both, I think the logic is not hard, but it makes it a little hard that remove()'s parameter (the path) is all relative to where I run the c program, so I have to find a way to add up the path when I go deep.

Comment: if you have a minute and you could help, that would be awesome, thanks

Comment: @JJLiu, you can "pass down" the full path name, based on `d` and `item`. I'll make a slight addition to the answer.

Comment: thanks. almost worked.  One thing, I am using readdir to get next item, there are 2 dirs that I want to skip "." and "..", how can I do that?  I editted:  `d = readdir(dp);
        while((strcmp(d->d_name,".") == 0 || strcmp(d->d_name,"..") == 0 ))
        {
            d = readdir(dp);
            if(d == NULL)
                break;
        }`  But I got infinite loop and seg falut

Comment: i added the small while loop just before closing the outer while loop

Comment: @JJLiu: I would leave the while loop as i had it and use an `if` within the loop to not do anything with `.` or `..`. What you have will process only those two and `.` is going to be problematic since you'll just keep processing the same directory over and over (until you run out of stack and crash). As you've already discovered :-) Updating with that info.

Answer (score 0):

You put all this in a function, accepting a string (which is the top path to be removed.) Then check `dit->d_type` for `DT_DIR`, and call the function recursively with the new path (old path plus the name).

Comment: where do you do the delete?  also, is d_type part of dirent?

Comment: @JJLiu, see paxdiablo's answer for the algorithm. Also check the `readdir` manual page.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest working in three passes: a first (recursive) pass determine which files should be removed and remember their directories, and a second pass actually delete the files (with `unlink` or `remove`), the last pass delete the empty directories (with `rmdir` or `remove`)

The [nftw](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xsh/nftw.html) function could be useful to you.

And there is always the possibility that some other process fill the directory you are removing.

Using `readdir` on a changing directory (i.e. on a directory in which you are removing files) could be error-prone.