# Removing directory recursively without using rm command

Tags: bash, shell, unix, recursion

Hi I am trying to remove/delete a directory along with its sub directories and files recursively. I don't want to use rm -r. I have come up with the following code.

```
 function recursive(){
            for i in "$1"/*; do

                    if [ -d $i ];then
                            echo "FILE $i IS A DIRECTORY"
                            if [ "$(ls -A $i)" ];then
                                    echo "DIRECTORY IS NOT EMPTY CALLING RECURSIVE AGAIN"
                                    recursive $i
                            else
                                    echo "DELETE THIS DIRECTORY: ITS EMPTY"
                            fi
                    elif [ -e $i ];then
                            echo "DELETING FILE $i"
                    else
                            echo UNKNOWN FILE $(basename $i)
                    fi
            done

    }
```

The problem is as I dig deep into sub directories, I can delete their files on the way, but once I reach the bottom of directory tree, I have to delete all the directories which are now empty (maybe on my way back up?)

Would really appreciate if someone could help me with its logic or guide me in the right direction.

The answer to [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7977501/recursively-remove-a-directory-using-c) question makes sense but I don't know how can it handle if there are few levels of sub directories ?

Comment: Once you reach the bottom of the directory tree, your deepest recursive() finishes its for loop.  Then it jumps to the next higher one, finishing `recursive $i`.  After the `recursive $i` call the directory should be empty, so perhaps delete the directory then.

Comment: "I want to drive a screw, but I don't want to use a screwdriver." *Why* don't you want to use `rm -r`? If nothing else, the answer to that could help us understand your requirements better.

Comment: I think he is doing it for educational purposes.

Comment: I have figured it out now... well basically I want to add the recycle bin functionality which means in reality i won't be deleting but moving it to the bin... but to just simplify I wrote it that way.

Comment: @CQQL: That's certainly plausible, but less useful than an actual statement from the OP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After you have deleted the contents of a directory you can delete it in any case. So just remove the else statement and move the remove-directory-command one level up:

```
function recursive(){
        for i in "$1"/*; do

                if [ -d $i ];then
                        echo "FILE $i IS A DIRECTORY OR A (SYM)LINK TO ONE"
                        if [ "$(ls -A $i)" ];then
                                echo "DIRECTORY IS NOT EMPTY CALLING RECURSIVE AGAIN"
                                recursive $i
                        fi

                        echo "DELETE THIS DIRECTORY: ITS (NOW) EMPTY"
                elif [ -e $i ];then
                        echo "DELETING FILE $i"
                else
                        echo UNKNOWN FILE $(basename $i)
                fi
        done

}
```

Comment: I think this makes sense... I have wrapped my head around it now... will give it a try and post the complete answer shortly

Comment: **DANGER**: This has the potential to very very bad unintended things when there are symlinks pointing outside the deleted tree

Answer (score 4):

I would simply use

```
find "$1" -delete
```

`unlink` is probably a nice thought too, but I'm not sure whether you'd consider that cheating :)